# "cannot be converted to String[] by method invocation conversion"

Tags: java

I am sure this is something stupid, but I can't figure it out for the life of me.... In the main method, when I am trying to create new artists, I keep getting an error on the creating a new "Recording" line (ie: surfacing and pop). It is saying it requires String, String[] but is getting String, MusicCollection.Artist. And it says "actual argument MusicCollection.Artist cannot be converted to String[] by method invocation conversion.

```
public class MusicCollection {

    private Artist[] artists = new Artist[100];
    private Recording[] recordings = new Recording[200];
    private int artistCount = 0;
    private int recordingCount = 0;

//toString method for MusicCollection
    public String toString() {

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        if (recordingCount > 0) {
            sb.append(recordings[0].toString());
            for (int i = 1; i < recordingCount; i++) {
                sb.append("\n" + recordings[i]);
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public class Artist {

        private String name;

        /**
         * Construct an artist object and add it to the collection.
         *
         * @param name the name of the Artist
         */
        public Artist(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            artists[artistCount++] = this;
        }

        /**
         * Retrieve the artist as a string
         *
         * @return the string representation of the artist
         */
        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }
    }

    public class Recording {

        private String name;
        private Artist[] artists = new Artist[100];
        private Track[] tracks = new Track[200];
        private int trackCount = 0;

        public class Track {

            private String name;

            /**
             * Construct track object and add it to the collection.
             *
             * @param name the name of the track
             */
            public Track(String name) {
                this.name = name;
                tracks[trackCount++] = this;
            }

            /**
             * Retrieve the track as a string
             *
             * @return the string representation of the track
             */
            public String toString() {
                return name;
            }
        }

        public Recording(String name, String Artist[]) {

            this.name = name;
            this.artists = artists;

            recordings[recordingCount++] = this;
        }

        public String toString() {
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(name);
            sb.append(" by " + artists + ": ");
            if (trackCount > 0) {
                sb.append(tracks[0].toString());
                for (int i = 1; i < trackCount; i++) {
                    sb.append(", " + tracks[i]);
                }
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MusicCollection mc = new MusicCollection();
        Artist sarahM = mc.new Artist("Sarah McLachlan");
        Recording surfacing = mc.new Recording("Surfacing", sarahM);
        Recording.Track surfacing1 = surfacing.new Track("Building a Mystery");
        Recording.Track surfacing4 = surfacing.new Track("Adia");

        Artist u2 = mc.new Artist("U2");
        Recording pop = mc.new Recording("Pop", u2);
        Recording.Track pop1 = pop.new Track("Discotheque");
        Recording.Track pop5 = pop.new Track("Miami");
        System.out.println(mc);
    }
}
```

Comment: `public Recording(String name, String Artist[]) {` Did you want an array of `String`s or an array of `Artist`s?

Comment: So declare the variable as being of type `Artist`. Currently it's declared as type `String` with a name of `Artist`.

Comment: Something like `public Recording(String name, Artist someArtist[]) {}` should probably work.

Comment: Actually, this line: `Recording surfacing = mc.new Recording("Surfacing", sarahM);` sort of tells me you want your constructor to be something like: `public Recording(String name, Artist someArtist) {}` since what you're passing is an `Artist` object and not an array of it.

Comment: Yeah Nicolás, That makes more sense and clears up all the errors, but for some reason when I am running with that code, I get output of:

Surfacing by [Lhw1.MusicCollection$Artist;@e86da0: Building a Mystery, Adia
Pop by [Lhw1.MusicCollection$Artist;@1754ad2: Discotheque, Miami

Comment: Getting unexpected hex values in your printouts usually means you forgot to implement .toString() on a class and are getting the default Object.toString() implementation.

Comment: Needed to have:
`public Recording(String name, Artist someArtist)`
and in my Recording class, only have:

    `private Artist artist;`
since I had already declared Artist as an array.
I also had to change `this.artists = artists;` to `this.artists = someArtist;`, since that was the variable I am passing. Worked like a charm after!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to have:
`public Recording(String name, Artist someArtist)`
and in my Recording class, only have:

```
private Artist artist;
```

since I had already declared Artist as an array.
I also had to change `this.artists = artists;` to `this.artists = someArtist;`, since that was the variable I am passing. Worked like a charm after!